# zomato api request with python requests library

Tags: python, json, python-requests, pycurl, zomato-api

Zomato which is one of the most popular restaurant search engines provides free api service...

If curl is used in api request, works perfectly;

```
curl -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" --header "user_key: MY_API_KEY_HERE" "https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/geocode?lat=41.10867962215988&lon=29.01834726333618"
```

But Python's `requests` library is used, it doesn't work. When I execute the code below;

```
import requests
r = requests.get("https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/geocode?lat=41.10867962215988&lon=29.01834726333618", headers={"user_key": "MY_API_KEY_HERE", "Accept": "application/json"});
```

interpreter returns the error below;

```
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: Cannot connect to proxy. Socket error: Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden.
```

Several attempts made via `pyCurl` library but unfortunately result is the same; `403 Forbidden`

How can I tackle this issue?

Comment: Even I get 500 error. PLease help

Answer (score 8):

I also had problems using Zomato API's. I was getting `500 Server Error`

Adding `User Agent` info in headers solved my problem.

```
import requests
from pprint import pprint

locationUrlFromLatLong = "https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/cities?lat=28&lon=77"
header = {"User-agent": "curl/7.43.0", "Accept": "application/json", "user_key": "YOUR_API_USER_KEY"}

response = requests.get(locationUrlFromLatLong, headers=header)

pprint(response.json())
```